# duplication of rows in table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which has many rows which are same, except for the `id` column. How can I show only one row for other duplicate row?

```
id    name     roll_number
1      a         1         
2      b         2         
3      a         1         
4      b         2       
5      c         3         
6      d         4         
7      d         4
```

show output like this

```
id    name     roll_number
1      a         1         
2      b         2                   
5      c         3         
6      d         4
```

Comment: Every name is always associated with the same roll number in your example (a=1, b=2, etc.). What do you want to happen if there are different roll numbers for the same name? Show one row per name or one row per name and roll number?

Answer (score 3):

We can use `DISTINCT ON` here:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (name) id, name, roll_number
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY name, id;
```

This query is selecting one record with the lowest `id` from each group of records having the same `name`.

Answer (score 2):

Simple aggregation using `min`

```
select Min(id), name,roll_number
from t
group by name, roll_number
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `numpy.unique(filt, trim='fb')` function:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.unique(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem requires to "filter out" tuples during the projection based on groups. The solution is to use distinct on.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (name, roll_number) id, name, roll_number
FROM table
ORDER BY name, id;
```

it basically creates groups by the attributes within the "DISTINCT_ON" and non-deterministically chooses one tuple, which it outputs.